# error: DevExpress NavBar must be copied to GAC

Tags: devexpress, gac, oneclick

When user opens the publish URL

```
           \\ourLanServer\appdir\someApp\publish.htm
```

and then clicks the Run button on the Microsoft-generated HTML page, an error is displayed that the DevExpress NavBar v10.1 must be copied to the GAC.

The app was published to a LAN server as FullTrust OneClick-enabled.
The CopyLocal property set to True for the DevExpress NavBar v10.1.

How to get beyond this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should include DevExpress assemblies to the list of published assemblies as it is explained in the [ClickOnce deployment of an application with Developer Express .NET Windows Forms components](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/AK3799.aspx)

Comment: Actually, the options in VS2010 are slightly different than what is given on the KB article cited. [I don't see a Prerequisite (Auto) in the list.]  In VS2010 they are Include (Auto);  Include; Prequisite; Exclude.  I had them set to Include (Auto). Before I could try the suggested approach, I deleted all references to XtraReports and removed the DLL references and republished, and all was working as expected. If I run into the problem again, I will try changing from Include (Auto) to Include. Thanks